QCombobox items invisible - only first item visible
Making a simple text editor to learn Qt and deepen my C++ skills.  I'm creating a font size drop down programmatically using QComboBox.
QComboBox *sizeComboBox = new QComboBox(this);
attributeToolBar->addWidget(sizeComboBox);
for (int i = 8; i <= 48; i += 2) sizeComboBox->addItem(QString::number(i));
connect(sizeComboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &MainWindow::setFontSize)

All the options are populated, but only the first is visible (8).

I scoured the internet, I asked ChatGPT, and looked through SO... I can't seem to find the problem nor a solution.
If more code is useful, below is .cpp file.
//TextEditor - just a simple text editor with various features
// by Hans Yunge 11/11/2024

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontComboBox>

//Main
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    textEditorToolBar();
    MainWindow::initializeDocument();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


//Actions
void MainWindow::on_actionNew_triggered()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    QString fileName;
    if (currentFileName.isEmpty() || currentFileName.isNull()){
        fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Open File", "C:\\Users\\hyung\\OneDrive\\Documents", "All Files (*)");
    } else {
        fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Open File", currentFileName);
    }

    QFile file(fileName);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QTextStream out(&file);
        out << ui->documentEditor->toHtml();
        file.close();
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{

        QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open File", "C:\\Users\\hyung\\OneDrive\\Documents", "All Files (*)");
        QFile file(fileName);
        currentFileName = fileName;
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
            QTextStream in(&file);
            QString tempString = in.readAll();
            ui->documentEditor->setHtml(tempString);

            file.close();
        }
    }

void MainWindow::initializeDocument(){

    ui->documentEditor->setAcceptRichText(true);
    ui->documentEditor->setHtml("<p>Beginning typing at will</p>");
}

void MainWindow::textEditorToolBar()
    {
            QToolBar *attributeToolBar = addToolBar("Document Attributes");

            // Actions
            QAction *boldAction = attributeToolBar->addAction("Bold");
            QAction *italicAction = attributeToolBar->addAction("Italic");
            QAction *underlineAction = attributeToolBar->addAction("Underline");

            // Connecting to slots
            connect(boldAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::setBold);
            connect(italicAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::setItalic);
            connect(underlineAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::setUnderline);

            // Font Drop Down
            QFontComboBox *fontComboBox = new QFontComboBox(this);
            attributeToolBar->addWidget(fontComboBox);
            connect(fontComboBox, &QFontComboBox::currentFontChanged, this, &MainWindow::setFont);

            // Font Size Drop Down
            QComboBox *sizeComboBox = new QComboBox(this);

            attributeToolBar->addWidget(sizeComboBox);
            for (int i = 8; i <= 48; i += 2) sizeComboBox->addItem(QString::number(i));

            connect(sizeComboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, this, &MainWindow::setFontSize);

    }

    void MainWindow::setItalic(){

        QTextCursor cursor = ui->documentEditor->textCursor();
        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setFontItalic(!cursor.charFormat().fontItalic());
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);

    }

    void MainWindow::setUnderline(){

        QTextCursor cursor = ui->documentEditor->textCursor();
        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setFontUnderline(!cursor.charFormat().fontUnderline());
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);

    }

    void MainWindow::setBold(){

        QTextCursor cursor = ui->documentEditor->textCursor();
        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setFontWeight(cursor.charFormat().fontWeight() == QFont::Bold ? QFont::Normal : QFont::Bold);
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);

    }

    void MainWindow::setFontSize(const QString &size){

        bool ok;
        int fontSize = size.toInt(&ok);
        if (ok && fontSize > 0) {
            QTextCursor cursor = ui->documentEditor->textCursor();
            QTextCharFormat format;
            format.setFontPointSize(fontSize);
            cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
        }

    }

    void MainWindow::setFont(const QFont &font){

        QTextCursor cursor = ui->documentEditor->textCursor();
        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setFont(font);  // Use setFont() to apply the entire QFont, including family
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
    }


I suspect it's simply too narrow. One-digit text fits, but two-digit text doesn't. Try populating it first, and then adding to the toolbar; I think it'll size itself to the widest item then.

What exact Qt version and on which os do you test this? It looks like windows 11. Start your app with '-style windowsvista'

I agree with Igor, when the combo is too small, even the elision dots won't appear in the popup (if large enough with the current font). Try adding the items before as suggested above, or changing the sizeAdjustPolicy to AdjustToContents.

@chehrlic you are the winner!!! Thank you sir.  added the preprocessor check for windows... set style to windowsvista and bamm!!! success... thank you sir for your contribution and saving my arse!!

adjusting size Policy to AdjustToContents unfortunately did not work, I tried that first as it seemed most reasonable to me... thanks for contribution and giving it a go... @IgorTandetnik

@denver-coder Note that the suggestion by chehrlic was probably intended for testing purposes, not as a solution. Setting the style only on that assumption is probably not a good idea, especially because it would make the widget appearance inconsistent (it may be fine for you, but remember that the purpose of SO is to provide solutions to anybody, not only those who ask questions). In fact, what you're facing may be a bug (and even a relatively important one) related to the QWidgetAction used in addWidget(), which may be caching the size hint ignoring updateGeometry() calls.

Thank you @chehrlic for a solution that worked.
Using on windows, adding the preprocessor OS check for windows and changing the style to 'windowsvista' if true, solved the immediate problem.
main.c

#include <QStyleFactory>

// if windows, set this style
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    if (QStyleFactory::keys().contains("windowsvista")) {
        a.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("windowsvista"));
    }
#endif


The windows11 style was new with Qt6.7 and has some issues. If this problem still occours with Qt6.8.0/.1 then you should fill a bug report.
